# Variable/method not found building solution on Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net

I was assigned to debug some legacy code in asp.net in my company, the problem is I don't know how to program in asp.net, though I did program in PHP and Grails before.
And the developers that knew asp.net left years ago.

I can't build the solution in Visual Studio because of some errors.
At first I was getting project reference errors, but I added the needed references to other projects.

Now I am getting 758 errors, and all of them are in the form:

> Error  *errorNumber*:  The name '*variableName*' does not exist in the current context X:\PATH\TO\FILE.aspx.cs *lineNumber*    *columnNumber*

or

> Error  *errorNumber*:  '*CustomPackage*.Web.Menu.MenuForm' does not contain a definition for '*variableName1*' and no extension method '*variableName1*' accepting a first argument of type 'Company.Srv.Web.Menu.MenuForm' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   X:\PATH_TO*ProjectName*\Menu\MenuForm.ascx.cs  *lineNumber*    *columnNumber*

where "*CustomPackage*.Web" is always the same.

Around 1/3 to 1/2 of the errors are of the latter form.
And all errors are in `.aspx.cs` files and (some)`.ascx.cs` files

---

As far as I could understand, the variables that are not found are the ones "declared" in `.aspx` files like that:

```
<customTagLib:dropdownlist id="ddlRegistros" runat="server" Width="70px">
...
</customTagLib:dropdownlist>
```

(Note that ddlRegistros stands for "drop down list Registros" (some sort of hungarian notation).)

And then, they are not recognized in it's respective `.aspx.cs` file when being referenced like the following:

```
int iNPaginas = Convert.ToInt32(ddlRegistros.SelectedItem.Value,10);
```

reporting the first error mentioned in this post.

Also, I am using Visual Studio to build the solution, I tried to clean and rebuild to no avail. I just got this project, so I wasn't able to get it working before.

Does someone have an idea how I can fix this problem?

Also, is the variable *ddlRegistros* really "declared" in the `.aspx` file as I mentioned above?

### Thanks for the attention

code for the `dropdownlist`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using Company.Literal;

namespace Company.Components.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Exibe um DropDownList na Página Web.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>
    /// Classe derivada da <c>System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList</c>, responsável por 
    /// exibir os DropDownLists da página do produto.</para>
    /// <para>
    /// Na criação do controle é automaticamente setada a classe de CSS "DropDownList" que irá fornecer a formatação
    /// padrão para o controle.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public sealed class DropDownList : System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList, ICampoDeNegocio
    {
        #region Definições
        private bool bPrimaryKey = false;
        private bool bPermiteModificacoesVisuais = false;
        private bool bTraduz = false;
        private string sRegraDeNegocioCampo = null;
        private string sRegraDeNegocio = null;
        private bool bRastreiaModificacoes = true;
        private bool bEhFiltro = false;
        //
        private Color cBackColor = Color.Empty;
        private Color cForeColor = Color.Empty;
        private string sCss = string.Empty;
        private bool bEVState = true;
        private string sMember = string.Empty;
        private string sTFString = string.Empty;
        private string sDTField = string.Empty;
        private string sDVField = string.Empty;
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtor da classe
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Seta o valor do CSS para "DropDownList", para que seja aplicada a formatação padrão 
        /// ao controle.</remarks>
        public DropDownList()
        {
            this.CssClass = "DropDownList";
        }

        #region EhChavePrimaria
        [Category ("Behavior")]
        public bool EhChavePrimaria
        {
            get { return bPrimaryKey; }
            set { bPrimaryKey = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region PermiteModificacoesVisuais
        [Category("Behavior")]
        public bool PermiteModificacoesVisuais
        {
            get { return bPermiteModificacoesVisuais; }
            set { bPermiteModificacoesVisuais = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region RastreiaModificacoes
        [Category ("Behavior")]
        public bool RastreiaModificacoes
        {
            get { return bRastreiaModificacoes; }
            set { bRastreiaModificacoes = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region EfetuaTraducao
        [Category ("Behavior")]
        public bool EfetuaTraducao
        {
            get { return bTraduz; }
            set { bTraduz = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region EhFiltro
        [Category ("Behavior")]
        public bool EhFiltro
        {
            get { return bEhFiltro; }
            set { bEhFiltro = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region RegraDeNegocio
        [Category("Data")]
        [TypeConverter (typeof(ValidatedBusinessConverter))]
        public string RegraDeNegocio
        {
            get { return sRegraDeNegocio; }
            set { sRegraDeNegocio = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region RegraDeNegocioCampo
        [Category("Data")]
        [TypeConverter(typeof(ValidatedBusinessFieldConverter))]
        public string RegraDeNegocioCampo
        {
            get { return sRegraDeNegocioCampo; }
            set { sRegraDeNegocioCampo = value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Escondendo atributos não liberados para os programadores
        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public override System.Drawing.Color BackColor
        {
            get { return cBackColor; }
            set 
            { 
                cBackColor = value; 
                base.BackColor = cBackColor;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public override System.Drawing.Color ForeColor
        {
            get { return cForeColor; }
            set 
            { 
                cForeColor = value; 
                base.ForeColor = cForeColor;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.ReadOnly(true)]
        public override string CssClass
        {
            get { return sCss; }
            set 
            { 
                sCss = value; 
                base.CssClass = sCss;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public override string DataTextField
        {
            get { return sDTField; }
            set 
            { 
                sDTField = value; 
                base.DataTextField = sDTField;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public override string DataValueField
        {
            get { return sDVField; }
            set 
            { 
                sDVField = value; 
                base.DataValueField = sDVField;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public override string DataTextFormatString
        {
            get { return sTFString; }
            set 
            { 
                sTFString = value; 
                base.DataTextFormatString = sTFString;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public override string DataMember
        {
            get { return sMember; }
            set 
            { 
                sMember = value; 
                base.DataMember = sMember;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
        public override bool EnableViewState
        {
            get { return bEVState; }
            set 
            { 
                bEVState = value;
                base.EnableViewState = bEVState;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Render
        /// <summary>
        /// Sobreposição do método <c>Render</c> herdado da classe base.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Efetua a tradução do texto do label antes do mesmo ser enviado para a página.</remarks>
        /// <param name="writer">Writer que será utilizado para efetuar o Render do controle.</param>
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            SortedList sList = new SortedList();
            if(bTraduz)
            {
                string sTextOrig;
                string sText;

                foreach(ListItem ddlItem in this.Items)
                {
                    sTextOrig = ddlItem.Text;
                    sText     = LiteralManager.GetLiteral(sTextOrig);
                    //
                    ddlItem.Text = sText;
                    sList.Add(sText, sTextOrig);
                }
            }

            base.Render(writer);

            // Restaura os textos dos itens
            if(bTraduz)
            {
                foreach(ListItem ddlItem in this.Items)
                    ddlItem.Text = Convert.ToString(sList.GetByIndex(sList.IndexOfKey(ddlItem.Text))) ;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And the code for one of the `.ascx.cs` files with errors of the second type(from the above mentioned). See one example of an `.ascx.cs` file below.

```
namespace Company.Prd.Web.Menu
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using Company.Literal;
    using Company.Functions.Web;


    /// <summary>
    ///     Summary description for MenuForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial  class MenuForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Se foi configurado para não mostrar o menu
            if(! this.MostraMenu)
                this.Menu1.Visible = false;
        }

        #region Web Form Designer generated code
        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
            //
            InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        ///     Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///     the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region MostraCabecalho
        public bool MostraCabecalho
        {
            get 
            { 
                PaginaBase parent = (PaginaBase) Page;
                return parent.MostraCabecalho;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region MostraMenu
        public bool MostraMenu
        {
            get 
            { 
                PaginaBase parent = (PaginaBase) Page;
                return parent.MostraMenu;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region MostraTitulo
        public bool MostraTitulo
        {
            get 
            { 
                PaginaBase parent = (PaginaBase) Page;
                return parent.MostraTitulo;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

and its respective `.ascx` file:

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" Inherits="Company.Srv.Web.Menu.MenuForm" CodeFile="MenuForm.ascx.cs" %>

<%@ Register tagprefix="cc1" Namespace="Company.Security.Web" Assembly="Company.Security" %>

<cc1:Menu id="Menu1" runat="server"></cc1:Menu>
```

It seems like there is no designer file generated, but if I right click in the `.aspx.cs` file and select *View Designer* on Visual Studio, then the designer file is open, but showing an `.aspx` file, and showing an error instead of the navigation bar of the site(the rest of the designer file is correctly shown, showing a form and some sample of results). The error shown is

> Error Rendering Control - Menu1. 
>   An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please post the code for the drop down list user control, you can find out the name of the file by looking at the top of any page using the control for something like this `<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Spinner" 
    Src="~/Controls/Spinner.ascx" %>`. The `Src` portion will lead you to the actual C# code for the user control.

Comment: Is the class in the code-behind file marked as `partial`? Does the `<%@ Page %>` directive use the `CodeFile` or `CodeBehind` attribute?

Comment: @RichardDeeming In the file `Wex009.aspx`, there is `<%@ Page language="c#" Inherits="Company.Product.Web.Wex009" CodeFile="Wex009.aspx.cs" %>`, plus some other `Register` tags, which I'm not completely sure what they do.

In the `Wex009.aspx.cs`, the class is declared as `public partial class Wex009 : Staff.Functions.Web.Zoom`

Comment: Are there any compilation errors in the user control file itself? Or all the errors in the .aspx file?

Comment: @KarlAnderson I'm not sure what is the user control file, but all errors are like the ones indicated in my post, and only happen on `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` files, and some in `ascx.cs` files

Comment: @user3046550 - user control = .ascx file and page = .aspx file.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Ok, there are no errors in `.ascx` files, but there are some in `.ascx.cs` files, and they have the exact same kind of error that is present on the `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` files

Comment: @user3046550 - Can you update your question with just the errors from the `.ascx.cs` file, along with the full code for the `.ascx` and `.ascx.cs` files? Please post it in the question and not the comments.

Comment: @user3046550 , do you have aspx.designer files for each webform?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder added more details about that

Comment: @user3046550 , OK, sorry then. I have had a similar issue when moving between dev environments, but that was concerning a web application. The fix was to delete the .designer files, and re-generate them by right clicking the aspx file, and choosing convert to web application. This seems to rebuild all the references to the objects used in that page. You should try converting one page to web application. It it does not work, just remove the .designer file.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was about generating designer files.

First of all, I misunderstood what designer files were.

Second, I had no idea I had to select "Convert to Web Application" to generate them.

Now I am having other errors, but that's something for another question.